MUI Persistent Drawer is not pushing the main content as the side nav slides in
I am using Next.js (Page) along with React\Ts and MUI Persistent drawer.
Trying to use Persistent drawer from MUI in the Next.js framework and I have Page.tsx and Layout.tsx. I am a bit confused about what I can add to Layout.tsx. The Persistent drawer I have split into 3 different components of Appbar, sidenav and content components. The content components should change when links in side nav is clicked and push the content a bit to the right as it appears, exactly as the MUI example. I am not able to push the main content , so I don't know where to add  . In each content component or the layout.tsx ?
The page.tsx has <main>, where I tried to add 'open' but gives error.
Layout.tsx
export default function RootLayout({ 
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
<>
<html lang="en">
      <body className= "m-0">
      <AppRouterCacheProvider>
        <Header/> 
        
            <main >
              <div className="mt-7" >
              {children}
              </div>              
            </main> 
            {/* <Footer /> */} 
        </AppRouterCacheProvider>
      </body>
    </html>  
</>  
  )
} 

Page.tsx:
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import Header from "./ui/Header/Header";
import SideNav from "./ui/SideNav/SideNav";
import { ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/client';
import client from './utils/apollo-client'
import '@/styles/globals.css'
import { AppRouterCacheProvider } from '@mui/material-nextjs/v13-appRouter';
export default function RootLayout({ 
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
  <>
    <html lang="en">
      <body className= "m-0">
      <AppRouterCacheProvider>
        <Header/> 
        
            <main >
              <div className="mt-7" >
              {children}
              </div>              
            </main> 
        </AppRouterCacheProvider>
      </body>
    </html>  
  </>  
  )
} 

I am not sure where to add <Main open={open}> as in the document of MUI, or is it even the reason why the content is not squeezed?

Please add your imports!

@mseyfayi added, please have a look.
